# The relationship between matrix rank and its characteristic polynomial coefficients

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

Given the matrix characteristic polynomial coefficients. Is there a quick way to determine the rank of the matrix?

Comment: I being trying to verify in matlab if the degree of characteristic polynomial equals to the rank of the matrix. I used matlab to generate a 20 by 20 sparse random matrix. The matlab rank command tells me that the rank of the matrix is 14, but using charpoly command which will give all the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial, the last 10 coefficients are zero while I'm expecting 6. I'm confused. If the rank is 14 or 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general nothing can be said about rank of the matrix by merely looking at char polynomial. Take $$A=\left[\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array}\right]$$ Rank$A=1$, though char polynomial is $x^2=0$. But if your matrix is diagonalizable, ''effective degree'' of the characteristic polynomial is equal to the matrix rank, since for a diagonalizable matrix, rank turns out to be number of non zero eigenvalues.

Comment: what is the "effective degree"

Comment: I am sorry, OP mentioned that term in a comment earlier, which I don't remember now.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p_A(X)=\sum c_i X^i$ be the characteristic polynomial of $A$. If rank$(A)<r$ then $c_r=0$: nul$(A)\geq n-r+1$, which is the geometric multiplicity of $0$, so the algebraic multiplicity of $0$ is greater or equal to $n-r+1$, hence $X^{n-r+1}$ divides $p_A$, so $c_n,\ldots,c_r=0$.

So rank$(A)\geq r$ if $c_r\neq 0$.

But the converse is not true: a nilpotent matrix has characteristic polynomial $X^n$ and may have rank up to $n-1$.

The closest satisfactory thing that can be said is the following: Let $A\in$Mat$_n(\mathbb{C})$, let $A^*$ be its transpose conjugate, and consider the characteristic polynomial of $AA^*$,
$$p_{AA^*}(X)=\det(XI_n-AA^*)=X^n-a_1X^{n-1}+\ldots+a_n.$$

Then rank$(A)\leq r$ iff $a_{r+1}=0$ and consequently rank$(A)=r$ iff $a_{r+1}=0$ and $a_r\neq0$.

In particular, the rank of $A$ is $n-k$, where $X^k$ is the highest power of $X$ dividing $p_{AA^*}$.

This happens because $a_r$ is the sum of the squares of the absolute values of all the minors of $A$ of order $r$.

Answer (score -1):

For a $n\times n$ matrix, if the characteristic polynomial is $X^mP(X)$ where $P$ is not divided by $X$, the rank is $n-m$.

Comment: So the effective degree of the characteristic polynomial should equal to the matrix rank?

Comment: This is false: a nilpotent matrix has characteristic polynomial $X^n$, but can have rank greater than 0. This is only true when the geometric and algebraic multiplicities of $0$ are the same.