# Relation between the rank of the matrix and its characteristic polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Is there some kind of relation between the rank of the matrix and its characteristic polynomial?After searching through various posts

Say if $A \in M_{5}(\Bbb{R})$ and its characteristic polynomial is $\alpha x^5 + \beta x^4 + \gamma x^3 =0 $,then the rank of matrix $A$ = ?

I am unable to estalish the relation ,like I know that from characteristic polynomial i can obtain the eigenvalues and hence the trace and determinant of the matrix and now the question is if i know the trace and determinat of the matrix can i obtain some information about the rank of the matrix(the number of linearly independent rows in the rref).

I was looking at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1639358/the-relationship-between-matrix-rank-and-its-characteristic-polynomial-coefficie) question but still i am not aware of any trick or relation.

Comment: Any reference\notes to these kind of problems is great ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the matrix is diagonalizable, rank = **degree of the characteristic polynomial minus the order of multiplicity of root 0** (in the example, the rank of the matrix is 5 - 3 = 2).

In fact, in this case, writing $M=PDP^{-1}$ with $D$ diagonal matrix with $n-r$ zeros, and transforming it into $MP=PD$, it means that if the columns of $P$ are denoted $P_k$, we have $MP_k=\lambda_k P_k$ with, say, the last $n-r$ vectors associated with eigenvalue $0$, (and only them) i.e. we have exactly $n-r$ independant vectors belonging to the kernel.

Answer (score 6):

Let $A$ be an $n$-by-$n$ matrix, and suppose that $0$ is a zero of the
characteristic polynomial with multiplicity $m\ge1$. Then the rank of $A$
can be any number between $n-m$ and $n-1$ inclusive.

Comment: For actually any other eigenvalue. The Jordan blocks form shows it need not be diagonizable (necessarily)

Comment: Jean Marie has included the condition of diagonalizability of the matrix?

Comment: @BAYMAX See also this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2340541/relation-between-rank-and-number-of-distinct-eigen-values/2340547#2340547 for supporting Lord Shark the Unknown's answer